# How to pass jQuery function value to variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this variable:

```
var tt_topiclist_fontsize = '{TT_topiclist_fontsize}';
```

and this small function:

```
$('input#TT_topiclist_fontsize.type-form').on('keyup', both);

function both(){
  window.opener.$('#header-site-description h1').css('fontSize', this.value + 'px');
}
```

So when I in input type in desired font size (some number), how can I pass that value to above variable ?

Thank you

Comment: Whats the linkage of `tt_topiclist_fontsize` and function?

Comment: functions is for change font size, while variable is for saving value.

Comment: `tt_topiclist_fontsize  =  this.value`

Comment: but at the same time will var tt_topiclist_fontsize = '{TT_topiclist_fontsize}';

Answer (score 0):

```
var tt_topicList_fontsize ;
$('input#TT_topiclist_fontsize.type-form').on('keyup', function both(){
window.opener.$('#header-site-description h1').css('font-size', this.value + 'px');
tt_topicList_fontsize = this.value;
});
```

try this!